# How to deploy and run Vue3 application on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, vuejs

I would like to create a Vue3 app which should run on SharePoint Online (Classic mode).
If here is someone who already did such a solution, please, could you describe me what everything I have to do to run Vue3 app on SharePoint?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am currently attempting this myself.

Have had some initial success using this approach https://github.com/BenRunInBay/vue3-spfx

Although, I have run into a bit of trouble with how to use vue-router :)

Basically, you create a Vue3 application however you want... I like this template: https://github.com/Sensanaty/vue3-vite-template

Within that project, you create a "webpart" directory... then you create your webpart in that newly-created directory.

It's a bit hacky, but it works to some degree.

You end up with a .sppkg file for the Sharepoint App Catalog

There's also been some recent updates in the 2 vue samples here: https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples

But both of these examples use vue 2 and node 8.

My approach allows at least Vue3 + Vite + Pinia + Axios + Node 14 with [SPFX 1.13.1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/release-1.13.1)

Comment: I got lost in your sentence: "Within that project, you create a "webpart" directory... then you create your webpart in that newly-created directory."
Could you describe it more deeply? I don't know how you can copy your project files and folders to SharePoint subsite and how to create a start page for the Vue app in there. Also don't know what .sppkg file means. Please, could you help me here? :)
If there is no way how to use Vue-router, then shouldn't be better to use React for SharePoint development?

Comment: I advise you to start with the https://github.com/BenRunInBay/vue3-spfx template ... closely read his instructions and read the comments throughout the project.

Comment: Thank you for your advise! This will take me some time, so will let you know the result later :)

Comment: The vue3-spfx project was recently updated and has changed quite a bit. 

You should give it a go now :)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help! Unfortunately, I have not been able to create Vue3 app for Sharepoint until now :( 

I don't understand the steps on the page https://github.com/BenRunInBay/vue3-spfx.

Step 2. Delete the .git folder and re-initialize this as your own git repo. ->
I copied the repo, have it opened in Visual Code but I don't know how should I "re-initialize" it and also don't know how to proceed with the further steps. I created a few simple apps using javascript but I don't understand these "buzz" words... 

Could you go through the setup with me, please?

Comment: That step about re-initialization only matters if you want to sync to your own little repo on github. You can skip it and play around with the code.

https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/14460/how-to-completely-reset-a-git-repository-including-untracked-files/

Might be able to help, if not, there are many articles about git + youtube videos that explain better than I can :)

You could also contact the guy behind vue3-spfx... I see he's on Twitter: https://twitter.com/BenRunInBay

He might be able to help.

Comment: Not sure where you are in your efforts. I tried to use the vue3-spfx system, but it was designed for older versions of SPFx and I can't get it to work for 1.16 and later versions of vite. Just curious if you ever got anywhere. I am still trying to get it all working with the latest versions.